# Changing the image of a SKSprite to an SKShapeNode

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skshapenode

Sprite Kit, Xcode.

I need to find a way to change a sprites image within the program itself. I know how to create jpg files and make them into the sprite image...

But for this program, I need to draw circles/polygons (which may change inside the program) using SKShapeNode, and then transferring this to the SKSpriteNode's image.

Let's say I have declared:

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite;
SKShapeNode *image;
```

How would I do this with these variables?

Thanks!

EDIT: I mean texture when I say image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can achieve what you're after using the `textureFromNode` method on `SKView`.

In your `SKScene`:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    SKShapeNode *shape = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:100];
    shape.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    shape.position  = CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.25, self.size.height * 0.5);
    [self addChild:shape];

    SKTexture *shapeTexture = [view textureFromNode:shape];
    SKSpriteNode* sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture: shapeTexture];
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.75, self.size.height * 0.5);
    [self addChild:sprite];
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Now the problem is, I seem to be using a different language from u... I've never seen the word "let"? Using SKSpriteKit, Xcode... Is that swift? I'm quite new to Xcode, btw so plz tell me if I'm wrong ^^

Comment: I've updated my answer :) It's been a little while since I wrote any Objective-C!

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? In my new program I need to directly change my texture in an already existing sprite, say from a triangle to a circle. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a SKSpriteNode image once you assign it. To do what you want, you need to create a SKSpriteNode using a texture.

```
- (instancetype)initWithTexture:(SKTexture *)texture
```

To change a SKSpriteNode's texture you assign a new texture using its texture property. You can also do this using an image converted to a texture like this:

```
myNode.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"imageName"];
```

As for a SKShapeNode, you cannot assign an image. Only a path, rect, circle, ellipse or points. Look at the SKShapeNode class docs section [Creating a Shape Path](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013025-CH1-SW18) for more info.

Comment: No... I meant I want to assign the SKShapeNode to the SKSpriteNode's image. So sprite.texture = SKShapeNode. When I say image in the question, I really meant texture, sry

Comment: @MasterShuriken - To my knowledge not possible.